# How To set MinWidth of whole application in uwp using visual states in xaml

Tags: uwp

I need to set application min width according to content size so that content dont hide when I reduce the size of app by dragging.Is doing that possible in xaml only.

I m using visual states to make design to be able to run on different screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

In UWP app, you can set the smallest size, in effective pixels, allowed for the app window using the [ApplicationView.SetPreferredMinSize(Size)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.setpreferredminsize#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_ApplicationView_SetPreferredMinSize_Windows_Foundation_Size_), such as calling the following code in the code behind,

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(new Size(300, 300));
```

But you can not access the ApplicationView and set its min size on the xaml directly. Besides, please also notice the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.setpreferredminsize#remarks) part about the size of app window.

> The smallest allowed minimum size is 192 x 48 effective pixels. The largest allowed minimum size is 500 x 500 effective pixels. If you set a value outside of these bounds, it is coerced to be within the allowed bounds.